# javascript replace class not working

Tags: javascript, html

i am using a javascript function to replace a class applied to an element but its not working.
code is as follows

```
function replace_class(kwe){
  var aq=document.getElementById('#il' + kwe);
  var rem=" xm14";
  aq.className=aq.className.replace(rem,"");
}
```

the above function is called when user clicks on the div. "KWE" is the numerical value which will be needed later to pinpoint that particular element.
the class which i want to remove is named as "xm14".

but nothing happening if i clicks on the element.

here is the html div code

```
 <div class="tryPond xm14" id="il1" onClick="replace_class(1);"><?php echo $getCatList[0]->getCatName();?></div>
```

Comment: How have you called the function?

Comment: @caolan <div onClick=""></div>

Comment: Preceding space may be optional? Try `replace(/\s*xm14/, "")`

Comment: *"but nothing happening if i clicks on the element"* A bit more information would be really useful. Is the function called at all? What is the value of `aq.className`? [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: i have used the preceding space bcoz there is one more class assigned to the div.

Comment: @felix yes i have tested using alert(), also i have checked the values of kwe

Comment: @user2365753: You're going to need the function between those quotes. `<div onclick="replace_class(kwe)"></div>` is what you want.

Comment: You could also consider using jQuery: `$(aq).removeClass("xm14");`

Comment: @evans  <div class="tryPond xm14" id="il1" onClick="replace_class(1);"><?php echo $getCatList[0]->getCatName();?></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element selector is wrong. Simple solution:

```
var aq = document.getElementById("il" + kwe);    // no "#" needed
```

Try that. Also consider using jQuery, it may make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: @evans its working fine now....i dont know why the hell i used both jquery nd javascript in one line...any ways thanx a lot...